# Calling another function with arguments

Tags: php, function

I'm pretty stuck here for what to do. I basically want to take all the arguments entered into function one:

```
func1('hey', 'hey2', 'hey3');
```

and then run func2 with the same arguments:

```
func2('hey', 'hey2', 'hey3');
```

I've tried this:

```
$arguments = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array($this, "func2"), $arguments);
```

but it doesn't seem to be working correctly? Any ideas?

Turns out the code should be:
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array(array($this, "func2"), $arguments[0]);

Woops :) Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you using functions or methods? If func1 and func2 are not methods of $this you should replace the array with only the function name.

Comment: I'm using methods. Sorry I forgot to mention that. So $x->func1() would have to call $x->func2()

Comment: You may wish to elaborate on "doesn't seem to be working". What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply like this :

```
 $func1 = func1('hey', 'hey2', 'hey3');

 func1($hey, $hey2, $hey3){

  //func1 stuff here

   $func2 =  func2($hey, $hey2, $hey3);

 }

func2($hey, $hey2, $hey3){

    //func2 stuff here

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function fun1(first,second,third) {
    return fun2(first,second,third);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass the arguments in an array, like so:

```
function func1(array $arguments) {
    list($hey, $hey2, $hey3, $hey4) = $arguments;
    func2($arguments);
}

function func2($arguments) {
    print_r($arguments);
}

$arguments = array('hey', 'hey2', 'hey3');

func2($arguments);
```